# What's is happening with the array elements?

Tags: arrays, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, memory-address

Everything seems to be fine. Except it is not working.

That is what is expected from this code:

```
Write a function that:

 Receives: a string;               (str)
          a letter;                (l)
          an address of an integer (&j)

 returns: an integer array;        (*(i + k))
          an integer value.        (j)
```

Each position of the array should contain the position where the letter was found. The integer value should contain the size of the created array

```c
#include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int *coincide(char *str, char l, int *j){
      int *i, k, u, n = strlen(str);
      for(k = u = 0; k < n; k++){
        if(l == str[k]){
          i = (int *) malloc(++u * sizeof(int));
          i[u - 1] = k;
          printf("i[%d - 1] = %d\n", u, i[u - 1]);
        }
      }
      *j = u;
      return i;
    }

    void main(){
      char str[] = "testtest", l = 't';
      int *i, j;
      i = coincide(str, l, &j);
      if(j > 0){
        for(int k = 0; k < j; k++) printf("i[%d] = %d\n", k, i[k]);
        puts("");
      }
    }
```

On linux the resuts are:

```
i[1 - 1] = 0
i[2 - 1] = 3
i[3 - 1] = 4
i[4 - 1] = 7
i[0] = 0
i[1] = 0
i[2] = 0
i[3] = 7
```

On windows the results appeared to be trash values instead of zeros. With only the last value being correct.

So, what exactly is happening with the array elements when the function is equaled to `i`?

And how to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your program?

Comment: `malloc` makes a new block of memory but you seem to assume it will extend the current block or something, look into `realloc`.  Also it is not clear why your loop in the `main` function starts outputting `i[-1]` since that will be outside the allocation.   Also, think about what `coincide` does if the letter is not found.

Comment: Hey mister @M.M , thanks to your feedback I managed to get it working! Thank you very much, it was just as simple as not assuming the malloc function would extend a given block.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @M.M's insight I got the program working with this change:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int *coincide(char *str, char l, int *j){
  int *i = NULL, k, u, n = strlen(str);
  for(k = u = 0; k < n; k++){
    if(l == str[k]){
        i = (int *) realloc(i, ++u * sizeof(int));
        i[u - 1] = k;
    }
  }
  *j = u;
  return i;
}

void main(){
  char str[] = "testtest", l = 't';
  int j, *i = coincide(str, l, &j);
  if(j > 0) for(int k = 0; k < j; k++) printf("i[%d] = %d\n", k, i[k]);
  if(j == 0) printf("\nThere's no ocorrence of '%c' character in '%s'\n", l, str);
}
```

Comment: It still returns an uninitialized pointer if the letter is not found; and you don't need the special case for `u == 0` because you can initialize `i` to `NULL` in the first place and use `realloc` every time (it is safe to realloc a null pointer)

Comment: That's true. I edited the code so it would match that line of thought of yours. 

I'm answering my own question, but it was only because of your help. Thank you!